# Retrieve text between quotes, including escaped quotes

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to retrieve the value of the fields in this SQL statement, however I am running into trouble with escaped quote characters:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `shops` VALUES (35723,'Counsel\'s kitchen');"
```

I am playing with variants of the following, none of which are satisfying:

```
re.select("\(\d*, '([^']*)',", sql);
```

That is:

```
\(\d*, '  Opening parentheses followed by any amount of numerals followed by a comma, followed by a space, followed by a single quote.
([^']*)   Retrieve all characters other than a single quote.
',        Single quote, comma
```

My best attempt so far:

```
re.select("\(\d*, '(\.*)','", sql);
```

That is:

```
\(\d*, '  Opening parentheses followed by any amount of numerals followed by a comma, followed by a space, followed by a single quote.
(\.*)     Retrieve all characters.
','       Single quote, comma, single quote.
```

**However, I would really like a way to express "Every character, including the two-character string `\'`, but not including the single character `'`"**. I had considered simply replacing `\'` with some obscure string, performing `'(\.*)'`, and then replacing the obscure string back with `'` (No escape character, as it is no longer needed). However, being Python, surely there is a cleverer way!

Note that the string is actually repeated many time in the real output, and that I do need all the values (ideally in a list):

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO `shops` VALUES (35723,'Counsel\'s kitchen','Some address'),(32682,'Anderson and his bar','12 Main street'),(32491,'Sid\'s guitar\'s string','Old London'),(39119,'Roger\'s wall',''),(45914,'David drinks a beer','New London');
"""
```

Comment: Let's say you could extract the values part. You may use [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/bY4xU8) `('|\")(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*\1|\d+`. If you don't get an answer, I'll try to get back to you later on.

Comment: @HamZa: Great to see you on SO! I'll play around with that regex and thank you for introducing me to the `regex101.com` site.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @HamZa: No, I'm avoiding it :) I'll get back to it soon and select an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, HamZa. I still cannot express the regex as I would like (Every character, including the two-character string `\'`, but not including the single character `'`) but I can parse the input and get the output that I need. I'm selecting an answer now.

Comment: @dotancohen Actually `(?:\\'|[^'])*` is exactly "Every character, including the two-character string `\'`, but not including the single character `'`"

Comment: Thanks, Jan. I'm now studying look-behinds and I'm starting to get the hang of it.

Comment: @dotancohen be careful :-) They can become very expensive. :P Speaking from painful experience…

Comment: Thank you Jan! I'll start benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildung upon @HamZa 's suggestion
when you can guarantee the single quotes it gets easier to group in bigger contexts:

```regex
'(?:\\'|[^'])*'
```

Otherwise, if you add other groups you have to update the backreferences

This also should be slightly faster as it has no lookahead - if you care. (According to regex page: 114 Steps opposed to 200 Steps)

If you need both, for performance reasons this would also work (escape `"` as needed)

```regex
'(?:\\'|[^'])*'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"
```

All of these solutions have a small flaw on corrupt input like

```regex
'Counsel\'s kitchen', 'tes\\t\'
```

the last group will still be matched!

[All together](http://regex101.com/r/pT1aM7)

Answer (score 1):

Could you say what version of Python you're using? On my 2.7, it seems to do the right thing with the escaped quote inside """ already, so then you can extract the data as a list of lists like this:

```
[re.split("'?,'",t.strip("'")) for t in re.findall("\((.*?)\)",sql)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I can get the regex to work, but I don't like how it is phrased (not maintainable, not flexible, depends on a specific ending). I would really like a way to express "Every character, including the two-character string `\'`, but not including the single character `'`".